# Sort and resort records with first sort still applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a view whereby a list of services are displayed. Within this view there are sort features such as buttons at the top which can be clicked to display only records which adhere to that option. For example clicking approved will only display approved services. I also have table columns which are clickable for sorting. So for example you can click date created and the table will display the records ascending or descending by date.

```
def index

  @my_campaigns = Campaign.active.where(:operator_id => current_user.operator_id).joins(:partner).where("partners.deleted_at IS ?", nil).where("partners.parent_id NOT IN (?) OR partners.parent_id is null", @sla_test_ids)

  @campaigns = @my_campaigns

  if params[:search_link]
    @campaigns = @campaigns.where(:status => params[:search_link])
  end

  if params[:search]
    @campaigns = @campaigns.where("campaigns.name ILIKE ? OR partners.company_name ILIKE ?",  "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%" )
  end

  if params[:sort]
    @campaigns = @campaigns.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  else
    @campaigns = @campaigns
  end

  if params[:page] == "all"
    @campaigns = @campaigns.order('campaigns.id DESC').page(1).per(@campaigns.count) # you can alhardcod' it
  else
    @campaigns = @campaigns.order('campaigns.id DESC' ).page(params[:page]||1)
  end

end
```

My problem is that say if I selected the approved button and only approved records were shown if I were to sort by date it would requery the database and return all records rather than just approved records.

Can anyone advise how I can combine the new parameters with the parameters already applied to the view.

Comment: You would need to pass in the existing params in the link. So when you click the link it has those parameters available

Comment: Instead of `if ... elseif`, do two `if`s. if a :search_link is provided do the call where. If a :sort is provided, call order.

Comment: @j-dexx How do you pass in the existing params in the link?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord relations are chainable so you can chain all your conditions one after another. For example:

```
@campaigns = @my_campaigns

if params[:search_link]
  @campaigns = @campaigns.includes(:partner).where(status: params[:search_link])
end

if params[:sort]
  @campaigns = @campaigns.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end
```

It's cheap because it's just the query construction. The entire query is executed only later, when you are using `@campaigns` in the view.

Comment: Hey. Its still returning the full list of records rather than my intended functionality where it returns a subset which are then ordered by date. I will update my question to include a bit more code. It might clarify/